# Copy data from USB

Tags: usb

I copied my files from my Windows 10 computer to a USB stick.
When I insert the stick into the USB port I can open the files on my Ubuntu computer (18.04.1).
I'm trying to copy them from the USB stick to my Ubuntu Files but can't figure out how. Tried dragging to the file icon on the dock with no success. Tried right click and "copy" but no "paste command when right click on File icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the official documentation: [Copy or move files and folders](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/ubuntu-help/files-copy.html.en)

Basically you just need to open a destination folder (i.e. the folder you want to copy the files into) instead of trying to use the Files icon. You can drag and drop into the destination folder, or right click inside the destination folder then you will see the "Paste" option.

Answer (score 0):

- Explanation

I guess you are trying to copy the files to a root directory (or any other that doesn't belong to your user).
To verify if this is the issue, open the file explorer and go to the destintation directory, then right click and select *Open in terminal*
Now execute `ls -la`

`ls` is a command to list the files and directories.
The parameter `-l` shows a "long list format" which includes the  owner user and group.
And the parameter `-a` shows the hidden files and dirs, the ones that begin with ".", for example ".bash_history", but in this case what interests us is the current dir, which is represented as "." (a period).

The output should look like this:

```
total 124
drwxr-xr-x  26 root root  4096 Feb  8 16:04 .
drwxr-xr-x  26 root root  4096 Feb  8 16:04 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 12288 Feb 11 11:28 bin
```

Look at the second line

```
drwxr-xr-x  26 root root  4096 Feb  8 16:04 .
```

This represents the current directory, 3rd and 4th column shows user and group owner, respectively, if 3rd column isn't your user then this is the problem.
This has to do with permissions too (the first column), but I will not explain it here beacuse is most likely not what you need.

---

- Solution

Open the file explorer, go to the usb dir, right click and *Open in terminal*.
Now execute:

```
sudo cp fileNameFromUSB /dessired/dir
```

That will simply copy the file you want to the dir you choose, the trick is the `sudo` part, which will execute the command as *root*, allowing you to copy the files wherever you need.

Btw, welcome to the community!